# How to get percentage download while downloading from Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Can I get the percentage of file that has been downloaded? I could not find anything related to that on firebase.google.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.

```
public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.Task task) {
double fprogress = (100.0 * task.getBytesTransferred()) / task.getTotalByteCount();
int bytes = task.getBytesTransferred();

String progress = String.format("%.2f", fprogress);
int constant = 1000;
if(bytes%constant == 0)
{
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
    .setContentTitle("Downloading " + model.getName())
    .setContentText(" " + progress + "% completed" );

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
   (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help mate!

Comment: Kindly mark it as answer if it is right so that it will help my career.